# React Export Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi check the code below ,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
let ok;
class Mydata extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          rif: [{
              "instituteName": "SEVILLE SCHOOL AND COLLEGE",
              "instituteAddress": "BALUBARI, SADAR, DINAJPUR"   
          } ]                      
        };
    }

render() {   
console.log(this.state.rif); 
  return (
      <div>
 check Console Log
     </div>
  );
  }
}

export default Mydata;
```

Here i am keeping some values in `this.state.rif` . I need to keep this value as global and want to export this `this.state.rif` to another component for re use. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using Parent and Child method

**`Mydata.js`** file

```
import NewComponent from './newComponent.js';

class Mydata extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          rif: [{
              "instituteName": "SEVILLE SCHOOL AND COLLEGE",
              "instituteAddress": "BALUBARI, SADAR, DINAJPUR"   
          } ]                      
        };
    }

render() {   
console.log(this.state.rif); 
  return (
      <div>
 Parent Component
    <NewComponent rif={this.state.rif} />
     </div>
  );
  }
}

export default Mydata;
```

Another component, `newComponent.js`

```
class NewComponent extends Component {

render() {   
console.log(this.props.rif); 
  return (
      <div>
 check Console Log newComponent
     </div>
  );
  }
}

export default NewComponent;
```

Comment: Thanks , it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

```
//moduleA.js
let object = {
    rif: 5,
};

export { object };

//MyData.js
import { object } from './moduleA'

class Mydata extends Component {
object.rif=this.state.rif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- **Parent component to Child  component** :  Use Prop
- **Child component to Parent component** : Use a callback and states